# Command-line Ruby gem with configuration block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, rubygems

My gem named "Falcon" runs from the command line. Using `ARGV` and `OptionParser`, I read command-line input and run the main Ruby classes in my app, no problem.

It can take a configuration block in an initializer file as long as it is called from Rails Console. Following [this basic pattern](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/mygem-configure-block), I've made it so that users can create an initialization file like the following:

```
# config/initializers/falcon.rb

Falcon.configure do |c|
  c.allowed_setting = 'value'
end
```

And then, in the Rails Console, I can do this:

```
Falcon.configuration.allowed_setting # => 'value'
```

However, when I run from the command line, the gem classes work not with their set configuration options, but as if no configs have been set. I suppose it is because executing from the command line doesn't go through the Rails environment with its pre-loaded initialization files.

I've tried running `bundle exec falcon [command]`, but that doesn't fix anything. Any ideas about how to get around this, so that the command line runs the gem with Rails configurations?

Comment: Why not require the initialization file instead? Does your gem really need to load the whole rails environment? Also you might want to take a look at [Slop](https://github.com/leejarvis/slop) which makes dealing with command line arguments a lot more enjoyable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no facility in Ruby to automatically load a configuration file. It's up to you to do so. You'need to ve been getting this behavior for free by running within a Rails environment where there *are* automatically-loaded configuration files, but you can't depend on this continuing to work outside of Rails.

You should add a `-c` or `--config` option to your program, that lets users specify the path to a configuration file, which you can load.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is Rails-focused, you may want to consider building an engine instead (as it makes integration and testing far simpler).

Also, check out `Application.initialize!`.